# Log4J2 - How to prevent it from appending?

Tags: java, log4j2

Here's my log4j2 configuration:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="INFO">
    <Appenders>
        <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n" />
        </Console>
        <File name="MyFile" fileName="logs\application.log" append="false">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d{YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n"/>
        </File>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Root level="debug">
            <AppenderRef ref="Console" level="error" />
            <AppenderRef ref="MyFile" level="info"/>
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

and here's how Log4J2 outputs to my file:

```
2020-07-15 12:09:40.449 [main] WARN  [MYAPP] - Values don't match: 
 First Map Key: [MYKEY] - First Map Value: [MYVALUE]
 Second Map Key: [MYKEY] - Second Map Value: [MYVALUE]

2020-07-15 12:09:40.449 [main] WARN  [MYAPP] - Values don't match: 
 First Map Key: [MYKEY] - First Map Value: [MYVALUE]
 Second Map Key: [MYKEY] - Second Map Value: [MYVALUE]
Values don't match: 
 First Map Key: [MYKEY] - First Map Value: [MYVALUE]
 Second Map Key: [MYKEY] - Second Map Value: [MYVALUE]
...
```

In my code; I'm informing Logger and Formatter as such:

```
import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;

private static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger([CURRENT_JAVA_CLASS].class);
private static final Formatter formatter = new Formatter();

...

formatter.format("Values don't match: \n First Map Value: %s \n Second Map Value: %s \n",
  firstMapEntry.getValue(),secondMapEntry.getValue());

logger.warn(formatter);
```

I don't want it to do this, I just want it to output the latest error, not concatenate it with the previous lines. Can anyone tell me how to do this?

Comment: It shouldn't. The message is just the key `$msg`. If you get the former message appended, then that **is** your msg. Maybe you are logging a growing `StringBuilder` or similar, and not resetting it?

Comment: Not that I can tell. I added code for how i'm trying it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have to wonder why you are doing it this way.  You could either do:

```
logger.warn("Values don't match: \n First Map Value: {} \n Second Map Value: {} \n", firstMapEntry.getValue(), secondMapEntry.getValue());
```

or

```
StringFormattedMessage msg = new StringFormattedMessage("Values don't match: \n First Map Value: %s \n Second Map Value: %s \n", firstMapEntry.getValue(), secondMapEntry.getValue());
logger.warn(msg);
```

or

```
private static final Logger logger = LogManager.getFormatterLogger([CURRENT_JAVA_CLASS].class);
logger.warn("Values don't match: \n First Map Value: %s \n Second Map Value: %s \n", firstMapEntry.getValue(), secondMapEntry.getValue());
```

The first option performs the best.  Your example will format the String even if the message isn't going to be logged. All the alternatives above will only format the string if the event will be logged.

Comment: Thank you rgoers, I was informed by SonarLint that Logger doesn't like appended values and that it recommended I use a Formatter. I will try and see if it allows me to use the comma seperated values in your first suggestion and get back to you.

Comment: Thank you, that worked. Green tick for you, good sir!